# Can I add to an Inherited Function?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, overriding

I have the following code:

```
    import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') #Sets the locale to 'English_Canada.1252'
class Employee():
    #Initlizes all of the info I need from the user
    def __init__(self, lastName, firstName, payRate):
        self.nameL = lastName
        self.nameF = firstName
        self.payRate = payRate #This payRate is an hourly pay rate
    #Prints out the first and last name of the Employee in the form Employee(FirstName LastName)
    def __repr__(self):
        return('Employee(' + self.nameF + ' ' + self.nameL + ')')
    #Changes the '+' key to add the hourlyPayRate of 2 Employee class types together   
    def __add__(self, otherSelf):
        sumOfPay = self.payRate + otherSelf.payRate
        return(sumOfPay)
    def printCheque(self, numberOfHoursWorked):
        if (numberOfHoursWorked > 40):
           grossIncome = (numberOfHoursWorked - 40) * (self.payRate * 2)
           grossIncome = grossIncome + (40 * self.payRate)           
        else:
            grossIncome = numberOfHoursWorked * self.payRate
        if(grossIncome > 42000):
            taxPaid = grossIncome * 0.22
        else:
            taxPaid = grossIncome * 0.15
        moneyMade = grossIncome - taxPaid           
        print('-'*80 + '\n')
        print('PAY TO: '+ self.nameF + ' ' + self.nameL + ' '*38 + 'AMOUNT: ' + locale.currency(moneyMade)+'\n')
        print('\n')
        print('Gross Pay: '+locale.currency(grossIncome) + '\n')
        print('Deductions: \n')
        print('   Tax     ',locale.currency(taxPaid), '\n')       
        return('-'*78)  
class SalariedEmployee(Employee):
    ''
    #payRate inherited from Employee will refer to salary here.
```

I have to make another Class similar to Employee but with this person getting a Salary over being paid on the hour.  The first thing i need to to do is change payRate to a salary.  I am not sure what this would look like and i have tried some things, but they didn't work.

The other thing I need to do is change printCheque to include another tax, and to also show vacation hours.  Would I be able to add something like this on to the function without defining a new one, or would I have to create an entirely new function?

Not really sure how to do either of these, and any help you can give would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest refactoring a little bit more...
It appears that hourly and salaried employees are two different types of Employees that should extend a base Employee class.

```
class Employee():
    #Initlizes all of the info I need from the user
    def __init__(self, lastName, firstName):
        self.nameL = lastName
        self.nameF = firstName

    def __repr__(self):
        return('Employee(' + self.nameF + ' ' + self.nameL + ')')

    def printCheque(self, grossIncome):
        if(grossIncome > 42000):
            taxPaid = grossIncome * 0.22
        else:
            taxPaid = grossIncome * 0.15
        moneyMade = grossIncome - taxPaid           
        print('-'*80 + '\n')
        print('PAY TO: '+ self.nameF + ' ' + self.nameL + ' '*38 + 'AMOUNT: ' + locale.currency(moneyMade)+'\n')
        print('\n')
        print('Gross Pay: '+locale.currency(grossIncome) + '\n')
        print('Deductions: \n')
        print('   Tax     ',locale.currency(taxPaid), '\n')       
        return('-'*78)


class HourlyEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, lastName, firstName, payRate):
        super(HourlyEmployee, self).__init__(lastName, firstName)
        self.payRate = payRate

    def __add__(self, otherSelf):
        sumOfPay = self.payRate + otherSelf.payRate
        return(sumOfPay)

    def printCheque(self, numberOfHoursWorked):
        if (numberOfHoursWorked > 40):
           grossIncome = (numberOfHoursWorked - 40) * (self.payRate * 2)
           grossIncome = grossIncome + (40 * self.payRate)           
        else:
            grossIncome = numberOfHoursWorked * self.payRate

        return super(HourlyEmployee, self).printCheque(grossIncome)


class SalaryEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, lastName, firstName, salary):
        super(HourlyEmployee, self).__init__(lastName, firstName)
        self.salary = salary

    def __add__(self, otherSelf):
        sumOfPay = self.salary + otherSelf.salary
        return(sumOfPay)

    def printCheque(self):
        cheque = super(SalaryEmployee, self).printCheque(self.salary)
        # Do Additional Tax Stuff and Add Vacation Hours
```

Doing the above should help resolve "I have to make another Class similar to Employee but with this person getting a Salary over being paid on the hour. The first thing i need to to do is change payRate to a salary. I am not sure what this would look like and i have tried some things, but they didn't work."

Using this class inheritance will give you the ability to alter attributes based on the type of employee.

Also, I've tried to refactor the printCheque function a little bit to show how using the super function could help abstract away some common functionality and then add functionality on a class level basis.  I'm not too sure what's going on with all the print functionality.  It may be better to use string formatting and return that in order to manipulate it based on different class instances.

Comment: What about doing it with out inheriting from a third class. Is there away to just inherit from Employee?  Or would I have to create that third class.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it all in one class. Just initialize objects within the methods instead of _init__.

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def __addHourly__(self, payRate, extraPay):
        pass

    def __addSalary__(self, salary, extraPay):
        pass

    def printHourlyCheque(self, payRate, hoursWorked):
        pass

    def printSalaryCheque(self, Salary, vacationDays, sickDays):
        pass
```

Then when you invoke the class, just use an if statement to choose which methods to invoke.

```
employee = Employee.repr()
status = some user input way to identify salary or hourly employee. 
    if status == 'Hourly':
        Employee.addHourly(payRate, extraPay)
        Employee.printHourlyCheque(payRate, #number of hours worked)
    elif status == 'Salary':
        Employee.adSalary
        Employee.printSalaryCheck(salary, #vacation days, #sick days)
```

The codes a little rough but the main idea is to define all the methods in one class, then use a conditional in main to invoke either the hourly related methods or the salary related methods. To do this, initialize objects within the methods themeselves instead of in **init**, except for universal object such as name.